# Duplicated row using TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance and CrudRepositroy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's pretend I have a super class A with a composite primary key (id1 and id2) and a generic value field, and two sub-classes: B and C.

Consider this case:
Table B:

```
+----------------+-------+
| id_1 | id_2    | value |
+------+---------+-------+
| 1    | 1       | 20.3  |
| 1    | 2       | 40.58 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

Table C:

```
+----------------+-------+
| id_1 | id_2    | value |
+------+---------+-------+
| 1    | 1       | 93.5  |
+------+---------+-------+
```

When I call the "findAllById1EqualsAndId2Equals" method from the CrudRepository with id1 = 1 and id2 = 1, the result is:

```
B(20.3), B(20.3)
```

When the proper result should be:

```
B(20.3), C(93.5)
```

How to solve this problem without creating a CrudRepositroy for each sub-class?

Comment: Is it `CrudRepository` that takes type parameter as superclass?

Comment: @Andronicus yes

Comment: Can you try with `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudReporitory`?

Comment: And please comment, if that helped

Comment: Changing from CrudRepositroy to JpaRepositroy did not help

Comment: I gave up and created a unique primary key. This solved my problem, but not as I liked it to be.